# STS maven project error with chromedriver

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I keep getting a red "!" on my maven project in STS Eclipse IDE. I import my fresh downloaded ChromeDriver from http://chromedriver.chromium.org/ and download ChromeDriver 72.0.3626.69 version which is the same version of my Chrome Browser on this PC. I even made sure to make a drivers folder to paste it in on my project. I add to my classpath and apply and get the red "!".

I also notice after downloading in my downlods folder in my file explorer on Windows 10 I notice chromedriver is hidden in file explorer when I try to add external jars when adding to class path. Not sure if this has anything to do with it.[image]

Comment: I am guessing that I should not put the driver in the classpath?

Comment: the red exclamation point is just there to tell you that your project is not up to date (following a change in your pom.xml) it has nothing to do with the chromedriver. Do you have an error in the execution of your tests?

Comment: click right > Maven > Update maven project ... > Update dependencies AND Force update of Snapshots/Releases

Comment: each time i remove chrome driver from the path the error goes away. It has I can update maven and no difference. I think that it's ok now that I excluded from the path and left it inside my driver folder instead. Thanks for the response Sgrillon.